# Segmentation Error in For loops while submission

Tags: c++, for-loop, segmentation-fault

This Code passed the Compile and run Test, but when I try to submit It in HackerRank, Its saying that it's a segmentation error.

```
// Sample code to perform I/O:

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n;
    int i;
    int a[i];

    cin >> n;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];        //Reading Input to STDIN
    }

    for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
       cout << a[i] << endl;        // Writing output to STDOUT 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

RESULT:  Runtime Error - SIGSEGV

Comment: `int a[i]` accesses uninitialized variable `i`, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior. What size is the array you create, in your opinion?

Comment: Maximum size is of 100

Comment: Can anyone Modify the code and explain me whats wrong I'm doing. I'm new To CP

Comment: Which part of your program code says "maximum size is of 100"?

Comment: It was just a constraint just like 1<=N>=100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is not initialized so you have undefined behavior. Never use a variable before initializing it.

Use vector instead of the array:

```
#include <vector>
int main() {
int n;
//int i; you don't need i anymore
vector<int> a;

cin >> n;
a.reserve(n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin >> a[i];        //Reading Input to STDIN
}
```

by using `int a[i];` you have two problems:

- `i` must be known in compile time(you cannot make it dynamic then)
- you store the array in stack memory, meaning the size will be very
  limited

[vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a container which allows you to resize the array anytime. It 
uses heap memory for storing data.

Comment: This is correct. Stack-allocated arrays can't be variable-length, and even if they could, using automatically managed data structures is still the right call. This is C++, after all, not C.

Comment: I'm facing Compilation error

Comment: @AmankhanRoohaani you need to include <vector>

Comment: I'm using g++ 5.4.0 or C++ 14 for clarification

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: Its working very well

Comment: @AmankhanRoohaani check the compile here https://godbolt.org/z/P_rP31

Comment: But can you please explain me this in detail Please

Comment: @oblivion Why was use of vectors necessary?

Comment: @AmankhanRoohaani I added some detail now, and am adding more in a second

Comment: My Solution is Accepted but I've got no score :(

Comment: We cannot help you with that, without knowing all the details of the test and of your submission. We are not psychics!

Comment: This is the link of the question @oblivion  : https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/tutorial/

Comment: Hey @oblivion My issue is reolved

Comment: Thanks For the Answer :) And all others you really helped me fast